# Playing with Radio button in wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

hi guyz how can i set my textbox readonly to true if the appropriate radiobutton is unchecked and vice versa also. same thing with datepicker,combobox focusable and ishittestvisible is equal to false when the appropriate button also is unchecked and vice versa... thanks

i found out that in wpf c#.. the radiobutton doesnt have checkedchange property. only in winform... here's what im goin to do

```
    private void rdbtn1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // <----This must CheckChange
    {
        if (rdbtndatecreated.IsChecked == true)
        {
            textBox1.IsReadOnly = false;
            DatePicker1.Focusable = true;
            DatePicker1.IsHitVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.IsReadOnly = true;
            DatePicker1.Focusable = false;
            DatePicker1.IsHitVisible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi keyboard thanks for the reply.. pls see my code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked.aspx) and [Unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.unchecked.aspx) events separately.

```
void rdbtn1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     textBox1.IsReadOnly = false;
     DatePicker1.Focusable = true;
     DatePicker1.IsHitVisible = true;
}


void rdbtn1_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
     textBox1.IsReadOnly = true;
     DatePicker1.Focusable = false;
     DatePicker1.IsHitVisible = false;    
}
```

Comment: whew! that's it.. thanks a lot.. i didnt see that uncheck.. gosh! so ashamed... :) you save my time... :)

Comment: No problem :) The reason your code didn't work was because it only fired when it was checked, so it would never hit the `else` part of the code.